# Hubot Not Responding to regex

Tags: regex, coffeescript, hubot, slack

I am working on a hubot slack integration, but have hit a bit of a brick wall. I am trying to get hubot to respond to this regex

```
(\d{4}\-){3}\d{4}
```

But for some reason it will not work.

#### Code Snippet

```
robot.respond /(\d{4}\-){3}\d{4}/i, (msg) ->
    msg.send "Words, Words, Words"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Austin

Comment: Try `hear` instead. Or try `/.*\b(\d{4}\-){3}\d{4}\b.*/i` with `respond`. Or even `/[\s\S]*\b(\d{4}\-){3}\d{4}\b[\s\S]*/i`.

Comment: And remove `i`, as there are no letters here - no need to check case sensitivity.

Comment: Turn `it will not work` into something very descriptive. Nobody is there to see what you are doing.

Comment: @stribizhev that worked.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hubot, the `respond` regex is *anchored*, so the whole string should match.

Thus, you need to either add `.*` or`[\s\S]*` on both ends of the regex. Also, I recommend to add word boundaries `\b` to make sure you match a whole word.

Thus, if there are newline symbols in the input, use

```
/[\s\S]*\b(\d{4}\-){3}\d{4}\b[\s\S]*/
```

If there are no newline symbols, just use

```
/.*\b(\d{4}\-){3}\d{4}\b.*/
```

Note the the case insensitive modifier is redundant here as there are no letters in the pattern.